# Eliminate symbols from Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm working with a list of roots of a 3rd order polynomial family, so i get a list this way:

```
Roots=Table[Reduce[Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D+l*x, x] == 0], {l, 150, 800, (800 - 150)/170}]
{x == 0.165706 || x == 0.21775 || x == 0.616544, 
x == 0.154518 || x == 0.230772 || x == 0.61471, 
x == 0.146629 || x == 0.240434 || x == 0.612937,.....}
```

So if I change "l" I get different roots set.
Then in order to reuse it in subsequent operations I exported it and in a text editor remove x == and ||  symbols so when i import back it I get this

```
{{0.165706, 0.21775, 0.616544}, {0.154518, 0.230772, 0.61471},{......},........}
```

So how do I get that inside mathematica

Comment: Maybe there are commas missing in your first equation? And the use of capitol `X` is different from small `x`. And there are brackets missing. In other words, your code is not a legal Mathematica output, so please correct the input so we can work with it.

Comment: The code you posted does not work. First of all, do not use UPPERCASE single letter. D means derivative.

Comment: The key is to use ToRules to transform the output of Reduce to rules and then use ReplaceAll (/.) to transform the rules into numbers. tip: do look at the bottom of the help page of functions you're working with. ToRules, for instance, is listed at the bottom of the Reduce help page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating answer since new input is now given.

```
Clear[x];
lst = {x == 0.165706 || x == 0.21775 || x == 0.616544, 
   x == 0.154518 || x == 0.230772 || x == 0.61471, 
   x == 0.146629 || x == 0.240434 || x == 0.612937};

z = Partition[Cases[lst, Or[Equal[x_, y___]] :> y, {2}], 3]

(*{{0.165706, 0.21775, 0.616544}, {0.154518, 0.230772, 0.61471}, 
    {0.146629, 0.240434, 0.612937}}*)
```

Comment: This solve my problem, also below answers work, but I understand better how this works.

Answer (score 2):

```
eqs = {{x == 312 || x == 534 || x == 686}, {x == 534 ||  x == 65464 || x == 5345}};
Partition[x /. ToRules @@@ eqs, 3]

(* {{312, 534, 686}, {534, 65464, 5345}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {x == 0.165706 || x == 0.21775 || x == 0.616544, 
       x == 0.154518 || x == 0.230772 || x == 0.61471, 
       x == 0.146629 || x == 0.240434 || x == 0.612937};

Last /@ # & /@ List @@@ lst
##2 & @@@ # & /@ List @@@ lst
x /. ToRules /@ # & /@ (List /@ lst)
List @@@ lst /. Equal -> (##2 &)
List @@@ lst /. Equal[a_, b_] :> b
```

> {{0.165706, 0.21775, 0.616544}, {0.154518, 0.230772, 0.61471}, {0.146629, 0.240434, 0.612937}}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 lst = {x == 0.165706 || x == 0.21775 || x == 0.616544, 
  x == 0.154518 || x == 0.230772 || x == 0.61471, 
  x == 0.146629 || x == 0.240434 || x == 0.612937};

List @@@ lst /. x == a_ -> a

(*  {{0.165706, 0.21775, 0.616544}, {0.154518, 0.230772, 
  0.61471}, {0.146629, 0.240434, 0.612937}}   *)
```

Have fun!